# Ударение с "шагами", "рядами" и "часами"

Tags: орфоэпия

Известно, что правильно в словах *шаг, ряд и час* делать ударение на окончание *-а* с числительными 2, 3 и 4. Также для всех очевидно, что правильно делать то же ударение и с другими числительными, оканчивающимися на 2, 3 и 4 (кроме оканчивающихся на 12, 13 и 14) в случае с *часами.* Не настолько очевидно то же для *шагов* и *рядов,* но, судя по всему, тоже верно. ***Правда?***

*Полчас**а*** то же на последний слог ударяют, так же как и *четверть час**а**,* в чём я убедился, загуглив это. Возникает вопрос, ***будет ли это верным для любых частей "шага", "ряда" и "часа"?***

Comment: Вы имеете в виду ударение этих словах в разных падежах? Я, если честно, не очень понял суть вопроса.

Comment: Не в разных, а в родительном, как получается с числительными. Например, *142 шага, 32 ряда, одна седьмая шага, треть/четверть ряда.*

Comment: Одна седьмая - будет, конечно, шАга. Обычный родительный падеж здесь явно побеждает.

Comment: шаг, -а и -у и (с колич. числит. 2, 3, 4) -***а***, предл. в ш***а***ге и в шаг***у***, мн. -и, -ов. См.: орфографический словарь Лопатина.

Comment: Да то, что Вы написали, Серж, и так понятно. Я же задал конкретные вопросы.

Answer (score 2):

Верно. Это всё рудименты двойственного числа.
Словарь Лопатина дает полш**а**г**а** и полр**я**д**а**, словарь "Русское словесное ударение" – только полшаг**а**.

Comment: Верно — это Вы о целых числительных?

Comment: О целых и о "полшага, полряда". Четверть что-то не встречал. Но ударение на последнем слоге почти наверняка не будет ошибкой.

Answer (score 1):

Это по Зализняку - счетная форма (одна из двух им выделяемых, вторая - у единиц измерения типа "пять ватт"). Она отличается от родительного падежа, как верно сказали, это рефлекс двойственного числа. Проявляется эта форма у очень небольшого числа существительных (односложных, мужского рода), но если уж проявляется, то последовательно и регулярно у всех сочетаний со всеми числительными такого рода, включая "пол" и "полтора". А вот при "треть часа" и "половина часа" эта форма не работает. Про "четверть" не могу сказать наверняка, вроде БЫ тоже не должно, это, как и треть, числительное другого происхождения.

Comment: Спасибо, Ирина! С большими тоже работает, правильно? Например, 1234 шага.

Comment: Да конечно, с оканчивающимися на 2, 3, 4 - это можно и не переспрашивать, если иное не оговорено особо, то в любом вообще контексте "числительные 2, 3, 4" понимаются как "оканчивающиеся на 2, 3, 4".

Comment: А-а, вот как! Интересно, запомню!